# failed to load resource signalr.js.map signalr core

Tags: javascript, ipad, asp.net-core-signalr

i am using SignalR core.  I have created a web site and I can use a JavaScript client to connect to the server hub. It works on Windows and iPhone.
when i try to test it via iPad it does not work.  I AM using an old version of iPad so maybe things have changed.

The simple client is:

```
function start() {
    try {
        connection.start();
        //await connection.start();
    } catch (error) {
        setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
    }
};

//async function start() {
//    try {
//        await connection.start();
//    } catch (error) {
//        setTimeout(() => start(), 5000);
//    }
//};

connection.onclose(() => {
    start();
});
```

Notice I had to comment out the async stuff as it was not recognized.

I connect my iPad to my iMac and use Web Inspection tools. I see  the error is:

```
signalr.js.mapFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (HTTP/2.0 404)

https://172.20.10.4/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js.map
```

I have searched for this file in my solution to see where it is being used but do not see anything...

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Snipe3000 none at all.  The older operating systems of iPad/iphone do not support SignalR it seems :(